# Build Failed while installing gobblin

Tags: gobblin

I am very new to Gobblin.
I am getting build failure while installing Gobblin.
Following is the terminal output:
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 17s
307 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 292 up-to-date

idl compatibility report:
Incompatible changes:
  1) Resource for "/home/m/TeamMembers/A/incubator-gobblin-release-0.14.0/gobblin-rest-service/gobblin-rest-api/src/main/snapshot/org.apache.gobblin.rest.jobExecutions.snapshot.json" is not found. This endpoint will not be released. Please remove this file and build again
  2) Resource for "/home/m/TeamMembers/A/incubator-gobblin-release-0.14.0/gobblin-rest-service/gobblin-rest-api/src/main/idl/org.apache.gobblin.rest.jobExecutions.restspec.json" is not found. This endpoint will not be released. Please remove this file and build again

[RS-I]:Resource for "/home/m/TeamMembers/A/incubator-gobblin-release-0.14.0/gobblin-rest-service/gobblin-rest-api/src/main/snapshot/org.apache.gobblin.rest.jobExecutions.snapshot.json" is not found. This endpoint will not be released. Please remove this file and build again
[RS-I]:Resource for "/home/m/TeamMembers/A/incubator-gobblin-release-0.14.0/gobblin-rest-service/gobblin-rest-api/src/main/idl/org.apache.gobblin.rest.jobExecutions.restspec.json" is not found. This endpoint will not be released. Please remove this file and build again

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you use the Gradle wrapper to build Gobblin:

```
./gradlew :gobblin-distribution:buildDistributionTar
```

This version of Gobblin uses Gradle 4.

See the [Getting started guide](https://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-Started/) for more details.